# Flicker when using Jquery ui slider in an Angular 2 component

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui, typescript, angular

I have integrated a jquery-ui slider plugin in an angular 2 component. It works great but with one nagging issue. The screen flickers when you slide. I have noticed that if I use the regular HTML5 slider, the screen does not flicker, transition is smooth, but this slider only supports one handle. How can I disable the flicker. I need guidance on where to look for the source of the problem. I have made a detailed [plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ElePVvqTAygpxJu9BxT3?p=preview) and put some comments in it.

```
export class RangeSlider implements OnInit {

@Input() value: any;
@Output() sliderChanged= new EventEmitter();

elementRef: ElementRef;
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = elementRef;
}
ngOnInit() {
    let that = this;
    let gradeLabels = ["K", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11","12"];
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.rangeSlider').slider({
        range: true,
       min: 0,
       max: gradeLabels.length-1,
        values: [0, 12],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
          let min = ui.values[0]
         let max = ui.values[1];
          min = (min == 0) ? "K" : min;
          let grade = (min == max) ? min : min + '-' + max;
          that.sliderChanged.emit(grade);
       }
    }).slider("pips", {
       rest: "label",
       labels:gradeLabels
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you experience the same with PrimeNG slider? It also uses the jQuery UI slider. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/slider

Comment: Thanks. I have not used the PrimeNG slider, but later found in the posted answer that this was an issue caused my design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you are replacing the reference to `activitiesArray` whenever you call `sliderChanged()`. This is causing the async pipe to unsubscribe to the old reference and resubscribe to your new one. This causes a momentary blip where there is no data. If you were to do the same with an Http request, it would be much more apparent.

I've forked and reworked your [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/LCw9Agn30ECdR1SuvoEN?p=preview) so as to not set the `activitiesArray` repeatedly and to be a little more 'reactive'. Note that it would be better to observe the output from the jquery slider rather than calling an event callback which pushes a subject.

changes to `src/app.component.ts`

```
htmlSlider=new Control();
jqSlider$=new Subject();
constructor(private _activityService: ActivityService) {
    let searchTerm$=this.term.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .startWith('');
    let activityList$=this._activityService.getActivityList();
    let searchedActivities$=activityList$.combineLatest(searchTerm$,this.searchFilter);
    let jqSliderFiltered$=searchedActivities$.combineLatest(this.jqSlider$.startWith(undefined),this.sliderSearch);
    let htmlSlider$=this.htmlSlider.valueChanges.startWith(undefined);
    let htmlSliderFiltered$=jqSliderFiltered$.combineLatest(htmlSlider$,this.gradePipe);
    this.activitiesArray=htmlSliderFiltered$;
}

searchFilter(activityList:Activity[],term: string):Activity[] {
    return activityList.filter(item=> item.description.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())));
}

sliderSearch(activityList:Activity[],term: string):Activity[]{
  if(!term)
    return activityList;
  return activityList.filter(item=> item.grade==term));
}

gradePipe(activityList,minGrade){
  if(!minGrade)
    return activityList;
  return activityList.filter(activity => parseInt(activity.grade.split("-")[0]) >= +minGrade);
}

sliderChanged(grade:any) {
 this.jqSlider$.next(grade);
}
```

changes to `activitymain.html`

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="12" [ngFormControl]="htmlSlider"  />
```